# Auto-scaling performance issues in Cloud Dataflow task from modified Google-provided template

Tags: python, maven, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow

I am starting to use Google Cloud Dataflow, attempting to launch a batch data processing pipeline to parse several hundreds of million records from Google Cloud Storage and save the result to BigQuery. Looking at the documentation, there is a perfect Dataflow template for this use case, [GCS_Text_to_BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-batch#cloud-storage-text-to-bigquery). I launched a task using the latest compilation of this template provided by Google (gs://dataflow-templates/latest/GCS_Text_to_BigQuery) and the performance was quite well (10-15 minutes processing time using a n1-standard-16 machine).

However, that compilation of the template was generated with a `WRITE_TRUNCATE` write disposition for BigQuery instead of the needed `WRITE_APPEND` (on April 13th this Java template was updated with this change on its [GitHub](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/templates/TextIOToBigQuery.java) repository but its updated compilation is not in the official GCS bucket yet). To use the template with the desired changes, I  compiled the updated code with the following command following the docs:

```sh
mvn compile exec:java \
-Dexec.mainClass=com.google.cloud.teleport.templates.TextIOToBigQuery \
-Dexec.cleanupDaemonThreads=false \
-Dexec.args=" \
--project=<gcp-project-id> \
--stagingLocation=gs://<gcs-bucket>/staging \
--tempLocation=gs://<gcs-bucket>/temp \
--templateLocation=gs://<gcs-bucket>/templates/text-io-to-bq.json \
--runner=DataflowRunner"
```

After launching the task with my own compilation of the modified template, the results are very different respect the ones using the provided by Google: auto-scaling seems to not be working in a proper way (the increase of workers during the task is very low and the process is never ending, in addition the % CPU consumption of the workers is very low). I am launching the task using the python API, with exactly the same parameters using official Google template and my own one:

```py
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

dataflow = build('dataflow', 'v1b3', cache_discovery=False)

# Compilation of template provided by Google (OK)
# dataflow_template = 'gs://dataflow-templates/latest/GCS_Text_to_BigQuery'

# Compilation of template build by me (NOK)
dataflow_template = 'gs://<gcs-bucket>/templates/text-io-to-bq.json'

parameters = {
    'javascriptTextTransformFunctionName': '<udf-function>',
    'JSONPath': 'gs://<gcs-bucket>/resources/schemas/<bq-schema-file>',
    'javascriptTextTransformGcsPath': 'gs://<gcs-bucket>/resources/UDF/<udf-file>',
    'inputFilePattern': 'gs://<gcs-bucket>/data/*',
    'outputTable': '<gcp-project>:<bq-dataset>.<bq-table>',
    'bigQueryLoadingTemporaryDirectory': 'gs://<gcs-bucket>/bq_temp_location/'
}

environment = {
    'tempLocation': 'gs://<gcs-bucket>/temp',
    'machineType': 'n1-standard-16'
}

request = dataflow.projects().locations().templates().launch(
    projectId='<gcp-project-id>',
    gcsPath=dataflow_template,
    location='<location>',
    body={
        'jobName': '<job-name>',
        'parameters': parameters,
        'environment': environment
    }
)

response = request.execute()
```

Any ideas on what could be the cause of this difference? Any support from your side would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: **UPDATE**: Google has updated today the compilation of ``GCS_Text_to_BigQuery`` template with ``WRITE_APPEND`` on their public ``gs://dataflow-templates`` bucket and using this new one the performance is OK. But I would like to know why I cannot achieve the same results with my own compilation, (I might need to modify it for my specific use cases in the future). Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are using the right version of Java?

Comment: I am using JDK 11.0.7 and Apache Beam SDK for Java 2.20.0.

Comment: **[SOLVED]**: The templates should be compiled using Java JDK 8 (using that Java version everything works as expected).

Comment: Great. Feel free to post it as an answer or let me know if I can do that for you

Comment: Hi @rmesteves, you can do it if it is OK with you, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, you need to use a specific `Java` version in order to compile your own templates.

In the GitHub [repository](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates) we can see that the right versions are `Java 8` and `Maven 3`

[image]